# Do i need <ProjectGuid> and <ProjectTypeGuids> in the new 2017 cps based project files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

In the old format you'd see code like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{AF007959-0830-4E90-9087-0B413BF83277}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
...
```

I'm in the process of migrating to the new CPS based project files.
Should i keep these tags or can i safely remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i need  and  in the new 2017 cps
> based project files?

The new sdk format project does not need to define the property `ProjectGuid` and `ProjectTypeGuids`.

It actually automatically generated and retrieved `ProjectGuid`and `ProjectTypeGuids` by the new project format `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"></Project>`.

**So you can just remove them and it is redundant to define them again.**

The `xxx.csproj` file of the new sdk project format is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  
  </PropertyGroup>
 
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

According [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.projectguid?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)

> Microsoft Internal Use Only.

If you use .NET 5 and higher, feel free to remove these definitions from the *.csproj file. :)

Comment: That's C++ documentation.  In the ProjectSdkElement, the ProjectGuid simply doesn't exist so it will be ignored.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.construction.projectsdkelement?view=msbuild-17-netcore